# How to stop a shell script running in the background?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I run the first shell script and it starts printing. I pause the execution using CTRL-Z. I give the bg command and the first shell script starts running. I run a second shell script. Now both the scripts are printing simultaneously. Now I need to stop the execution of the first shell script only and the second shell script should continue printing. What commands can I use to do this ?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: You can't do it without pausing the second script.

Comment: Why don't you run them in separate terminal windows?

Comment: Open a second terminal window. Use `ps` to find the PID of the first script, and kill it with the `kill` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you catch the PID of each execution you can stop one of them with kill command

```
myCommand & echo $!
```

You can write a script for run the two command and catch the PID of each of them and stop the one you want with kill command.

Comment: But you have to pause the second script first so you can type a command.

Comment: You can also use job numbers: `kill %1`

Comment: In this case it would be `bg ; echo $!`

Comment: I need to stop the first script without pausing the execution of the second script. Is this possible ?

Comment: @ScienceRocker Not in the same terminal window.

Comment: With a shell script you can... But why do you need to start two jobs and stop the first before ?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop `command2`, send the signal to stop `command1` and then let `command2` continue

```
$ command1&
[1] 42510
$ command2
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 command2
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 command1 &
[2]+  Stopped                 command2
$ kill -STOP %1

[1]+  Stopped                 command1
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 command1
[2]-  Stopped                 command2
$ kill -CONT %2
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 command1
[2]-  Running                 command2 &
```